# pharmacy vs. drugstore in American English

Tags: word-meaning, american-english, synonyms

Is there a clear-cut difference between **pharmacy** and **drugstore** in American English? Does a pharmacy necessarily sell medicines and drugs and nothing else? Could a pharmacy sell make-up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the United States, there can be little practical difference between the two. "Pharmacy" is simply a *formal* term for what often amounts to the same thing.

To be clear:  A "pharmacy" is a business (or a part of a hospital) that dispenses medication.  A *public* pharmacy does not have to sell other products, but many do because it helps them make money.  When people come in to buy drugs they're often inclined to buy all sorts of related products, including cosmetics.

Meanwhile, a "drugstore" is often a larger store that includes a pharmacy, and usually also sells various convenience products like cosmetics, personal care products, snack foods, household products, stationery, and seasonal items.

In effect, a "pharmacy" is a store that sells drugs and various other products, and a "drugstore" is one that includes a pharmacy, and also sells other products.  You can see why it's hard to distinguish one from the other.

Whether someone uses "drugstore" or "pharmacy" may depend on various factors, such as what is available around where they live. It may be that the only nearby store that sells conveniences like make-up or toothpaste, is the local "pharmacy".  Possibly something like this:

[image]

In larger communities, pharmacies are mostly part of large chain "drug stores", although some smaller pharmacies still exist.

The point is that,  if you say, "I'm going to the pharmacy," then it's likely you're going to purchase medication -- unless it's understood that the local pharmacy is where you go to buy other things.  On the other hand, "I'm going to the drugstore," can mean pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. When you use the word pharmacy you generally are referring specifically to the counter where drugs are dispensed. So we have things like "CVS Pharmacy" where CVS is a large drugstore chain, but this refers exclusively to their actual prescription fulfillment business. And when you say "I'm going to the pharmacy", generally that implies your primary focus is the act of buying medicine, even though store itself may have general merchandise. As for store names, you'll see both interchangeably, although it's typically only small shops in medical buildings that use 'Pharmacy' as part of the store's name.

Comment: The answer for British English would be almost the same, except we use **chemist** (or **chemist's**) to mean the shop, where most of the shop will sell soap, shampoo, make-up etc, and a small portion will be the **pharmacy**, with the **pharmacist** where they sell prescription medicines.  In a hospital there's only a pharmacy and no "chemist".  We don't use the word "drug store" except in relation to American things, and "drug" is never used for "medicine" except in specifically medical or academic situations.

Comment: "CVS Pharmacy" is the official, trademarked name of the chain and of each of its stores, which sell many things other than medicines. The same is, I think, true of several other large drugstore chains -- they use 'pharmacy" as part of the official names for the entire store and the chair.